# How to crop a multi-page (image/scanned) pdf file (which won't crop with pdfcrop)?

Tags: command-line, pdf, scanning, imagemagick

Usually, I'm pretty happy using [`pdfcrop`](http://pdfcrop.sourceforge.net/), even though the cropped output usually consumes significantly more disk space. Note that comparable [code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42236/pdfcrop-generates-larger-file) *does* exist, which addresses and resolves this issue. However, if wanting to crop a scanned (image) pdf file, my impression is that `pdfcrop` simply fails. I imagine that [`ImageMagick`](http://www.imagemagick.org) is capable of doing the trick, possibly by (also) making us of [`pdftk`](http://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-cli-examples/).

I'm looking for an efficient one-liner of code (a multi-line script would also be ok...) to crop such a pdf file from Top-Bottom-Left-and-Right by x cm each (or, better yet, by a b c d cm, individually), going all the way from input.pdf to output.pdf.

ps: the solution needn't involve `ImageMagick`; I'm happy as long as it works (cleanly, reliably and efficiently)... ;)

Comment: a genius just answered this question programmatically [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/27721)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Full credit is due to [AlexG](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1053/alexg) who incidentally *en passant* posted a solution to this problem [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42259/27721), which, for completeness sake and so it doesn't get lost (!), I quote below.

Relevant to the above question is the **trimming** option described in the `man`:

> Usage examples:
>
> ```
> #default operation
> pdfcrop.sh orig.pdf cropped.pdf
> pdfcrop.sh -m 10 orig.pdf cropped.pdf
> pdfcrop.sh -hires orig.pdf cropped.pdf
>
> #trimming pages
> pdfcrop.sh -t "10 20 30 40" orig.pdf trimmed.pdf
> ```
>
> Content of `pdfcrop.sh`:
>
> ```bsh
> #!/bin/bash
>
> function usage () {
>   echo "Usage: `basename $0` [Options] <input.pdf> [<output.pdf>]"
>   echo
>   echo " * Removes white margins from each page in the file. (Default operation)"
>   echo " * Trims page edges by given amounts. (Alternative operation)"
>   echo
>   echo "If only <input.pdf> is given, it is overwritten with the cropped output."
>   echo
>   echo "Options:"
>   echo
>   echo " -m \"<left> [<top> [<right> <bottom>]]\""
>   echo "    adds extra margins in default operation mode. Unit is bp. A single number"
>   echo "    is used for all margins, two numbers \"<left> <top>\" are applied to the"
>   echo "    right and bottom margins alike."
>   echo
>   echo " -t \"<left> [<top> [<right> <bottom>]]\""
>   echo "    trims outer page edges by the given amounts. Unit is bp. A single number"
>   echo "    is used for all trims, two numbers \"<left> <top>\" are applied to the"
>   echo "    right and bottom trims alike."
>   echo
>   echo " -hires"
>   echo "    %%HiResBoundingBox is used in default operation mode."
>   echo
>   echo " -help"
>   echo "    prints this message."
> }
>
> c=0
> mar=(0 0 0 0); tri=(0 0 0 0)
> bbtype=BoundingBox
>
> while getopts m:t:h: opt
> do
>   case $opt
>   in
>     m)
>     eval mar=($OPTARG)
>     [[ -z "${mar[1]}" ]] && mar[1]=${mar[0]}
>     [[ -z "${mar[2]}" || -z "${mar[3]}" ]] && mar[2]=${mar[0]} && mar[3]=${mar[1]}
>     c=0
>     ;;
>     t)
>     eval tri=($OPTARG)
>     [[ -z "${tri[1]}" ]] && tri[1]=${tri[0]}
>     [[ -z "${tri[2]}" || -z "${tri[3]}" ]] && tri[2]=${tri[0]} && tri[3]=${tri[1]}
>     c=1
>     ;;
>     h)
>     if [[ "$OPTARG" == "ires" ]]
>     then
>       bbtype=HiResBoundingBox
>     else
>       usage 1>&2; exit 0
>     fi
>     ;;
>     \?)
>     usage 1>&2; exit 1
>     ;;
>   esac
> done
> shift $((OPTIND-1))
>
> [[ -z "$1" ]] && echo "`basename $0`: missing filename" 1>&2 && usage 1>&2 && exit 1
> input=$1;output=$1;shift;
> [[ -n "$1" ]] && output=$1 && shift;
>
> (
>     [[ "$c" -eq 0 ]] && gs -dNOPAUSE -q -dBATCH -sDEVICE=bbox "$input" 2>&1 | grep "%%$bbtype"
>     pdftk "$input" output - uncompress
> ) | perl -w -n -s -e '
>   BEGIN {@m=split /\s+/, $mar; @t=split /\s+/, $tri;}
>   if (/BoundingBox:\s+([\d\.\s]+\d)/) { push @bbox, $1; next;}
>   elsif (/\/MediaBox\s+\[([\d\.\s]+\d)\]/) { @mb=split /\s+/, $1; next; }
>   elsif (/pdftk_PageNum\s+(\d+)/) {
>     $p=$1-1;
>     if($c){
>       $mb[0]+=$t[0];$mb[1]+=$t[1];$mb[2]-=$t[2];$mb[3]-=$t[3];
>       print "/MediaBox [", join(" ", @mb), "]\n";
>     } else {
>       @bb=split /\s+/, $bbox[$p];
>       $bb[0]+=$mb[0];$bb[1]+=$mb[1];$bb[2]+=$mb[0];$bb[3]+=$mb[1];
>       $bb[0]-=$m[0];$bb[1]-=$m[1];$bb[2]+=$m[2];$bb[3]+=$m[3];
>       print "/MediaBox [", join(" ", @bb), "]\n";
>     }
>   }
>   print;
> ' -- -mar="${mar[*]}" -tri="${tri[*]}" -c=$c | pdftk - output "$output" compress
> ```

Answer (score 13):

You could try **[briss](http://briss.sourceforge.net/)**. It's pretty simple, but does the job. It's a GUI app though.

Download the zip file and extract to a folder of your choice and start it:

```
java -jar briss-0.9.jar
```

To install it permanently and system-wide and be able to start it from anywhere with just `briss`, you would unpack the download in `/usr/local/lib/`, then create an executable file `/usr/local/bin/briss` that contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar /usr/local/lib/briss-0.9/briss-0.9.jar
```

Comment: This method fails on certain files, see [this bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/briss/bugs/51/)

Comment: When it fails, this can be resolved by first printing the pdf to file, using a document viewer like Evince

Answer (score 10):

This here is the best and easiest and has a wonderful GUI: Krop

Download deb from the author: http://arminstraub.com/computer/krop

Review: http://www.hecticgeek.com/2013/08/crop-pdf-ubuntu-13-04-krop/

Edit: I am using krop since 13.10 and I noticed that the latest versions started to support opening a pdf with krop via right click. I also switched to the snap version since it became available and it supports also right click, confirmed on 18.10 - 20.04. The GUI is not as colorful with the snap version but functionality is the same:

```
sudo snap install krop
```

Comment: I really like this one. GUI is nice for lots of irregular crops. Allows cropping different selections from the same page into a multi-page pdf. Great! Thanks!